# Can I use SATA3 drives in a SATA2 RAID

Tags: hard-drive, raid

My RAID5 using HighPoint RocketRAID 1740 just died, I had 4 disks and 2 of them died while moving the computer. So I need to make a new RAID. The two old disks that still work are Western Digital Caviar Blue, WD10EALX. So I am wondering if I need to get a new RAID controller since that is made for SATA1 and SATA2 or since SATA3 is backwards compatible with SATA2 can I then just get 2 SATA3 disks and add them into the WD10EALX setup and build a new RAID from the mix of SATA2 and SATA3? Of course it will then function as SATA2 that is for certain, just wondering if that is something I can do or do I need to get a new controller for SATA3 disks?

I am wondering about this problem since all the hard disks resellers no longer sell SATA2, only SATA3.

Comment: SATA3 devices are backwards compatiable with SATA2.  What might make it not compatible is the storage size of the SATA3 drive.

Comment: Ok, so the RAID controller doesn't care, he just sees that the device is SATA2 compatible and uses it. Excellent :-)